# When there is a virtual function in a class, is the implicitly generated destructor virtual too?

Tags: c++, destructor, virtual-destructor

Suppose we have a class

```
class A
{
    virtual void f();
};
```

Will the default destructor be virtual?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**. The destructor is always non-`virtual` unless you explicitly say that it's `virtual` or the class has a base class with a `virtual` destructor.

Comment: Well, I guess I just found a major memory leak in my code then... Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Is this in the spirit of "don't pay for what you don't use"? (i.e. it doesn't need to be virtual unless you are inheriting from, yes yes i know a virtual function would indicate that but ...)

Comment: @Borgleader The destructor doesn't even need to be virtual if you're inheriting from it. It is only needed for deleting polymorphically.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes I know, I glossed over that because comment length, and it wasn't necessary to get the answer I wanted, but I guess it's important to not for other users who might come across this answer and it's comments. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I'd just add that the class is already **polymorphic**, which supports the polymorphic behaviors of `typeid` and `dynamic_cast`. That is, a virtual destructor is not needed for that. But it's needed for `delete` via pointer to base class.